# Using Wild card for removing directory in dos

Tags: batch-file, directory, wildcard, command-prompt, dos

I am working on a application that needs to remove folders from inside a folder. BUT the Folder name will have the same general name minus the end of it. `NA_monthlyGP_20130131`, The numbers will change. It is housed in this following path `C:\Inbound\Extract` I want to remove it but keep the parent directory, `Extract`.

Comment: why is this tagged ms-dos? does this actually apply to a version of DOS or Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

double the % signs to use it in a batch file.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("C:\Inbound\Extract\NA_monthlyGP_*") do rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the command line:

```
for /d %i in (NA_monthlyGP_*) do rd "%~i"
```

Comment: Start it from your `Extract`  folder.

Answer (score 0):

`forfiles /P C:\Inbound\Extract /M NA_monthlyGP_* /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /s /q @file"`

[forfiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forfiles) allows command line users to run commands for each file in a location. Available in Windows Vista/Server 2003 and later.

```
/p  pathname    Indicates the path to start searching. 
                The default folder is the current working directory (.).
/M  searchmask  Searches files according to a searchmask. 
                The default searchmask is '*' .
/C  command     Indicates the command to execute for each file. 
                Command strings should be wrapped in double quotes. 
                The default command is "cmd /c echo @file".
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this command answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (Mentioning the versions `forfiles` works in would be a start.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy updated the description. Let me know if you'd like to see additional remarks. Did you use this solution? Why did you comment?

Comment: It came up in the LQP queue, and I didn't particularly want others to have a bad excuse to delete it.